# jQuery await ajax call on form submitHandler and strange redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function populateAndSend() {
    var _url = "..." + var1 + var2 + var3
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: _url
    })
};

$('#tryitForm').validate({
    rules: {
        ...
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $.when(populateAndSend()).then(form.submit()); <<< does not work
    }
});
```

2 problems, `when().then()` doesn't seem to work, and when the `form.submit()` is fired, it redirects me back to my page, but adds `var1`, `var2` and `var3` as arguments to my page, so lets say my site url is http://localhost/home/index it would redirect me to http://localhost/home/index?var1=xxx&var2=xxx&var3=xxx?
I cant understand why this is happening?

Final version:

```
// function call, to pass message to telegram bot
function populateAndSend() {
    var _url = "..." + var1 + var2 + var3

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: _url
    })
};
// form validation
$('#tryitForm').validate({
    rules: {
        xxx
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        populateAndSend();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `form.submit()` in the submit handler, the form submission is being done using `$.ajax()`. Change to:

```
$('#tryitForm').validate({
    rules: {
        ...
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        populateAndSend();
        return false;
    }
});
```

`return false;` in the submit handler tells the validation plugin not to do normal form submission.

Comment: That sounds like you're not preventing the default action in the `.submit()` handler.

Comment: It needs to return `false` to prevent the default action.

Comment: any tips on achieving that in conjunction with `submitHandler`?

Comment: Oh, you shouldn't need to do anything if you're using the jQuery validate plugin, it doesit automatically.

Comment: `form.submit()` performs the normal form submission. What do you have in the `action` attribute of the form?

Comment: If the form uses `method="get"`, then submitting the form simply redirects to the action URL, with all the form fields added as URL parameters.

Comment: I don't have words `action` or `method` anywhere on my form, I'm not even aware what those do. I don't seem to find any examples how to submit form with jqueryvalidate apart from `form.submit()`

Comment: This is basic HTML for forms. `action` specifies the URL that the form submission should send to, and you need to use `method="get"` or `method="post"` to tell it what HTTP method to use when submitting the form. By default, the action is the same URL as the page containing the form, and `method` is `GET`.

Comment: This is basically doing what would happen if you didn't use the validation plugin to check the form first. When you submit the form, it redirects to `index?name=val&name=val&...`

Comment: so you are suggesting I'm not actually using it? (the plugin)

Comment: Sure you are. The plugin works by doing validation checks. If they succeed, it submits the form. If you have `submitHandler` it calls your function, otherwise it submits the form itself. Your submit handler submits the form. What are you expecting to happen instead of redirecting to the URL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136004/discussion-between-4c74356b41-and-barmar).

Comment: If you want to submit using AJAX, then don't use `form.submit()`. The `$.ajax` call in `populateAndSend()` does that.